# Auto detect and install text font in android

Tags: android, fonts, currency, currency-formatting

In my app, I want to format a text as many type of currency. Such as $ for USD, đ for VND, £ for GBP, € for EUR,...
Some currency code can not be shown in right way when I parse JPY (Japan),CNY (china),KPW (Korea),... because of missing of appropriate font.

How can I make my app display all of currency code in any android phone? Or, is there any way to auto detect text font and ask user to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all symbols in your `String` resource and then you can access that symbol by name of the item in a `String` resource.

or you can make a function like

```
public static String getCurrencySymbol(Context context, String currency){
        if(currency.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")) return "$";
        if(currency.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP")) return "£";
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Jackal, maybe you don't understand my question. In android, we can use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().setCurrency(); to format a price with specified currency. But some currency symbol can not be shown in right way. (such as currency symbol of china, Korea, Japan,...) And I am finding a way to detect a font to display this symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way to do it automatically. What you can do is experiment with various fonts and save the ones you need in `assets/fonts` of your Android project. In your code, you can check for the Unicode value of the currency symbol, and if it is not supported or appropriate in the current font, switch to the appropriate font which supports it.

Comment: Thanks, but there are total >170 type of currencies. So, I think your solution may not be the best.

Comment: This works, I also used method like that in my project, however there is a problem if single text field contains multiple languages, is there a way to apply multiple fonts at same time to single text field and make android auto-detect which one to use? If not then how to make android apply font to substring, not to entire content of a TextField?